# return is causing program to ask for input twice

Tags: java, eclipse, input

I've written the following program and it does what its supposed to except for the fact that it asks for the input twice. I'm positive that the reason it asks for the input twice is because of the *return* because when I tried the same code in a *void* method it only asks for the input once.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foothill
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String theString, maskString, removeString;
      char keyCharacter;
      int keyCount;
      input = new Scanner(System.in);

      getKeyCharacter();
      keyCharacter = getKeyCharacter();
      getString();
      theString = getString();
      maskCharacter(theString , keyCharacter);
      maskString = maskCharacter(theString , keyCharacter);
      removeCharacter(theString , keyCharacter);
      removeString = removeCharacter(theString , keyCharacter);
      countKey(theString , keyCharacter);
      keyCount = countKey(theString , keyCharacter);
      input.close();

      System.out.println("String with '" + keyCharacter + "' masked");
      System.out.println("" + maskString + SEPERATOR);
      System.out.println("String with '" + keyCharacter + "' removed");
      System.out.println("" + removeString + SEPERATOR);
      System.out.println("# of " + keyCharacter + ": " + keyCount);               
   }

   public static char getKeyCharacter()
   {
      String userInput;
      char keyCharacter;
      int characterLength;

      do
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter a SINGLE letter to act as key: ");

         userInput = input.next();           
         characterLength = userInput.length();         

      }
      while (characterLength != 1); 

      keyCharacter = userInput.charAt(0);     
      return keyCharacter;      
   }

   public static String getString()
   {      
      String theString;
      int stringLength;

      do
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter a phrase or sentence >= 4 "
            + "characters: ");

         theString = input.next();
         stringLength = theString.length();

      }
      while (stringLength < MIN_CHAR || stringLength > MAX_CHAR);

      return theString;    
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are calling `getKeyCharacter()` twice?

Comment: Ohhh. I didn't even see that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
getKeyCharacter();
keyCharacter = getKeyCharacter();
getString();
theString = getString();
```

with:

```
keyCharacter = getKeyCharacter();
theString = getString();
```

Comment: yup.  I got it now. Thanks so much!